# jquery menu widget position last submenu differently

Tags: jquery, menu, position, submenu

i'm using the jquery ui menu widget to make a horizontal top level menu with vertical submenus that drop down below the top level items on hover. the submenus are left aligned with the top level items. that works fine for the first 5 items, but the last one has some long items in the submenu, longer than the top level item, so the submenu sticks out of the right side of the container. i'd like to make just the last submenu right aligned with its parent.

the menu is created with this:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#main-nav" ).menu({ icons: { submenu: "ui-icon-blank" }, 
                          position: { my: "left-8 top", at: "left bottom" } });   
});
```

that does everything just right except the last submenu. i've tried adding

```
$( "#sub-about" ).menu( "option", "position", { my: "right+8 top", at: "right bottom" } );
```

and

```
$( "#sub-about" ).position({  my: "right+8 top",  at: "right bottom"});
```

and even tried just positioning the ul directly with

```
$( "#sub-about" ).css("left", -100);
```

but nothing happens. i don't see any errors, but the last submenu doesn't move. how can i make just the last submenu get position `my: "right+8 top", at: "right bottom"`

html is this:

```
<div id="main-nav-container"><!-- // start nav 118439, main -->
<ul id="main-nav">
<li><a>solutions</a>
<!-- // start subnav of item 693, nav 118439 -->
<ul class="solutions">
<li><a href="international-data-acquisition.htm">International Data Acquisition</a></li>
<li><a href="us-high-volume-marketer.htm">US High Volume Marketing</a></li>
<li><a href="data-enrichment-data-append.htm">Enrichment & Append Services</a></li>
<li><a href="data-compliance-services.htm">Data Compliance Services</a></li>
<li><a href="global-market-intelligence.htm">Global Market Intelligence</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- // end subnav of item 693, nav 118439 -->
</li>
<li><a>expertise</a>
<!-- // start subnav of item 695, nav 118439 -->
<ul class="expertise">
<li><a href="case-studies.htm">Case Studies</a></li>
<li><a href="data-sourcing.htm">Data Sourcing</a></li>
<li><a href="global-projects.htm">Global Projects</a></li>
<li class="no-hands"><a>Industry Expertise</a></li>
<li class="inset"><a href="expertise-automotive.htm">Automotive</a></li>
<li class="inset"><a href="expertise-financial-services.htm">Financial Services</a></li>
<li class="inset"><a href="expertise-technology.htm">High Tech</a></li>
<li class="inset"><a href="expertise-insurance.htm">Insurance</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- // end subnav of item 695, nav 118439 -->
</li>
<li><a>resources</a>
<!-- // start subnav of item 697, nav 118439 -->
<ul class="resources">
<li><a href="data-catalogs.htm">Data Catalogs</a></li>
<li><a href="gmdi-reports.htm">GMDI Reports</a></li>
<li><a href="newsletters.htm">Newsletters</a></li>
<li><a href="events.htm">Events</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- // end subnav of item 697, nav 118439 -->
</li>
<li><a>clients</a>
<!-- // start subnav of item 699, nav 118439 -->
<ul class="clients">
<li><a href="clients.htm">Clients</a></li>
<li><a href="case-studies.htm">Case Studies</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- // end subnav of item 699, nav 118439 -->
</li>
<li id="top-about"><a>about</a>
<!-- // start subnav of item 701, nav 118439 -->
<ul id="sub-about" class="about">
<li><a href="news-press.htm">News & Press</a></li>
<li><a href="leadership.htm">Leadership Team</a></li>
<li><a href="careers.htm">Careers</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- // end subnav of item 701, nav 118439 -->
</li>
</ul>
<!-- // end nav 118439, main -->
</div> <!-- #main-nav-container -->
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get this right using the default collision option (flip) by setting the correct container with `within:`. without specifying it was defaulting to window. once i set it to the container i didn't want to overflow it worked perfectly. code that works is:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#main-nav" ).menu({ icons: { submenu: "ui-icon-blank" }, 
    position: { my: "left-12 top", at: "left bottom", within: "#slideshow-container" } });
});
```

thanks